# Photoview image boundaries don't change

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using Chris Banes' PhotoView along with Universal Image Loader in a ViewPager. Everything works well, except that when an image is enlarged, whether it be by double tap or gesture, the  image does enlarge, but the images' original dimensions don't change. Meaning that if, for example, the image displays at 100x200, the image can be enlarged, but the `ImageView` is still 100x200. I've tried calling `PhotoView` in the code instead of `ImageView`, but the result is the same. And I've tried calling `uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView` in the `ViewPager` XML instead of `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`, but again, no change, the image dimensions don't expand with the image. Here's my code:
**Pager Activity:**

```
    import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.myapp.tnt.TNTConstants.Extra;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.FailReason;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageScaleType;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.SimpleImageLoadingListener;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.FadeInBitmapDisplayer;

import uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView;
import uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoViewAttacher;

/**
 * @author Sergey Tarasevich (nostra13[at]gmail[dot]com)
 */
public class UILPager extends BaseActivity {

private static final String STATE_POSITION = "STATE_POSITION";
DisplayImageOptions options;
ViewPager pager;
PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.uil_viewpager);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String[] imageUrls = bundle.getStringArray(Extra.IMAGES);
    int pagerPosition = bundle.getInt(Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, 0);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        pagerPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_POSITION);
    }

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true).cacheOnDisc(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.NONE)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

    pager = (HackyViewPager) findViewById(R.id.uil_impager);
    pager.setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter(imageUrls));
    pager.setCurrentItem(pagerPosition);

}// --- END onCreate

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(STATE_POSITION, pager.getCurrentItem());
}

private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private String[] images;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    ImagePagerAdapter(String[] images) {
        this.images = images;
        inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View container) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
        View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.uil_viewpager_item,
                view, false);
        ImageView phView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById (R.id.uil_vpager_image);
    // Attach a PhotoViewAttacher, which takes care of all of the zooming functionality.
    mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(phView);
    final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.uil_vpager_prog);
    imageLoader.displayImage(images[position], phView, options, new     SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View   view,
                            FailReason failReason) {
                        String message = null;
                        switch (failReason.getType()) {
                        case IO_ERROR:
                            message = "Input/Output error";
                            break;
                        case DECODING_ERROR:
                            message = "Image can't be   decoded";
                            break;
                        case NETWORK_DENIED:
                            message = "Downloads are denied";
                            break;
                        case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                            message = "Out Of Memory error";
                            break;
                        case UNKNOWN:
                            message = "Unknown error";
                            break;
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(UILPager.this, message,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show    ();

                        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                            View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });

        ((ViewPager) view).addView(imageLayout, 0);
        return imageLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View container) {
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.splash, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    UILPager.this.finish();
}
}
```

And here's the XML for the **Pager Items:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="1dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/uil_vpager_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/descr_image" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/uil_vpager_prog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Has anyone run into this, if so, what's the fix? I'm using SDK 10, and am getting the same result on my Android 2.3.4 phone and my Android 4.3 Tablet

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. There were a couple of things I was doing wrong. The main one being: for the `PhotoView` to be able to expand beyond the borders of the original image, you can't put it into an `ImageLayout`, you have to create a PhotoView (not ImageView) in code, not in XML. So here's my corrected Pager Activity:

```
    package com.myapp.wcbc;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.myapp.wcbc.TNTConstants.Extra;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.FailReason;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageScaleType;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.SimpleImageLoadingListener;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.FadeInBitmapDisplayer;

import com.myapp.wcbc.HackyViewPager;
import uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView;
import uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoViewAttacher;

/**
 * @author Sergey Tarasevich (nostra13[at]gmail[dot]com)
 */
public class UILPager extends BaseActivity {

private static final String STATE_POSITION = "STATE_POSITION";
DisplayImageOptions options;
ViewPager pager;
PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.uk_vp);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String[] imageUrls = bundle.getStringArray(Extra.IMAGES);
    int pagerPosition = bundle.getInt(Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, 0);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        pagerPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_POSITION);
    }

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true).cacheOnDisc(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

    pager = (HackyViewPager) findViewById(R.id.uk_pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter(imageUrls));
    pager.setCurrentItem(pagerPosition);

}// --- END onCreate

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(STATE_POSITION, pager.getCurrentItem());
}

private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private String[] images;

    ImagePagerAdapter(String[] images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View container) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        PhotoView phView = new PhotoView(container.getContext());
    // Attach a PhotoViewAttacher, which takes care of all of the zooming functionality.
    mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(phView);
    final ProgressBar spinner = new ProgressBar(container.getContext());
    imageLoader.displayImage(images[position], phView, options, new     SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View   view,
                            FailReason failReason) {
                        String message = null;
                        switch (failReason.getType()) {
                        case IO_ERROR:
                            message = "Input/Output error";
                            break;
                        case DECODING_ERROR:
                            message = "Image can't be   decoded";
                            break;
                        case NETWORK_DENIED:
                            message = "Downloads are denied";
                            break;
                        case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                            message = "Out Of Memory error";
                            break;
                        case UNKNOWN:
                            message = "Unknown error";
                            break;
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), message,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show    ();

                        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                            View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });

    container.addView(phView, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        return phView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View container) {
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.splash, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    UILPager.this.finish();
}
}
```

I was right, though. All the magic that needed to be tweaked is in `instantiateItem()`.